# facebook: how to store and retrieve access_token on server side?

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine

I am trying to understand, how facebook authentication works and how the flow should look like. I am working with Google App Engine and I have managed to obtain first the code and then access token. Using it I can for example retrieve user's friends list. This is all cool.

However, how can I store this access_token? I wan to allow my user to access different pages in my facebook app and I will need this access token on those pages. How can I store it and how can I retrieve it? Or maybe no matter which page user accesses I first need to get the code and then access token and only then can I perform some operations on his behalf?

I don't want to use javascript sdk for now. Is it possible to do it all from server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I store this access_token? I
>   wan to allow my user to access
>   different pages in my facebook app and
>   I will need this access token on those
>   pages. How can I store it and how can
>   I retrieve it?

just store the access_token in the datastore. 
https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py
line 50.

It is from the facebook python sdk.
https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/

If you don't want to use javascript sdk, you need to see this document. It has all details for facebook Oauth.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

While facebook redirect your user to your page assigned by redirect_uri. It will give your the code (A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER), then your server can get the user's access_token/facebook id with server side facebook api + code. Then you can login your user (set the session/cookie) and do whatever you want.

Comment: This is cool, but this python library assumes you have authenticated the user through java script sdk. Is this possible to somehow have session set only through server side.

Comment: So basically I need to have my own sessions, right? Set session cookie by myself and have pair session/access_token in the database, so the access token can retrieved in further requests?

Comment: Exactly, since you don't use javascript sdk, you need to manage the session cookie on your own.

Comment: "Your server can get the user's access_token/facebook id with server side facebook api + code." OK but it seems to me the question is **how** to do that? That developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication gives one PHP example but doesn't really say how this is supposed to work.